# TreeTable Design

Tags: sapui5

I've got a problem with the sap.ui.table.TreeTable which also occurs for some colleagues.
I had a look at the [Fiori Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/ui-components/tree-table/) for the table and I like the style with the arrows which fits the normal SAPUI5 style. 
After including the TreeTable in my application, [it has a really inapplicable style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaPQZ.png).

Now my question: How do I achieve the desired look? Am I doing anything wrong or am I missing any additional styles or options?

Infos:

- using SAPUI5 1.38.7
- used Table: sap.ui.table.Treetable
- Controller:

  ```
  var testModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
      var testData = { 
          data:{
              subItems:[
                  {
                      name:"NAME 1",
                      subItems:[
                          {
                              name:"NAME 1-1",
                              subItems:[
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 1-1-1"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 1-1-2",
                                      subItems:[
                                          {
                                              name:"NAME 1-1-2-1"
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              ]
                          },
                          {
                              name:"NAME 1-2",
                              subItems:[
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 1-2-1"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 1-2-2",
                                      subItems:[
                                          {
                                              name:"NAME 1-2-2-1"
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      name:"NAME 2",
                      subItems:[
                          {
                              name:"NAME 2-1",
                              subItems:[
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 2-1-1"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 2-1-2",
                                      subItems:[
                                          {
                                              name:"NAME 2-1-2-1"
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              ]
                          },
                          {
                              name:"NAME 2-2",
                              subItems:[
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 2-2-1"
                                  },
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 1-2-2",
                                      subItems:[
                                          {
                                              name:"NAME 1-2-2-1"
                                          }
                                      ]
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  },
                  {
                      name:"NAME 3"
                  },
                  {
                      name:"NAME 4"
                  },
                  {
                      name:"NAME 5",
                      subItems:[
                          {
                              name:"NAME 5-1"
                          },
                          {
                              name:"NAME 5-2",
                              subItems:[
                                  {
                                      name:"NAME 5-2-1"
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              ]
          }
      };
      testModel.setData(testData);
      this.getView().byId("sapEquipmentTree").setModel(testModel,"testModel");
  ```
- View

  ```
  <t:TreeTable
      id="sapEquipmentTree"
      rows="{path:'/data', parameters: {arrayNames:['subItems']}}"
      selectionMode="MultiToggle"
      enableSelectAll="false"
      ariaLabelledBy="titleSAPTree">
          <t:toolbar>
              <Toolbar>
                  <content>
                      <Title id="titleSAPTree" text="HEADER" />
                  </content>
              </Toolbar>
          </t:toolbar>
      <t:columns>
          <t:Column width="13rem">
              <Label text="ColumnHeader"/>
              <t:template>
                  <Text text="{name}"/>
              </t:template>
          </t:Column>
      </t:columns>
   </t:TreeTable>
  ```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.38, an explicit form factor CSS class has to be set (e.g. sapUiSizeCozy) in order to get the arrow style.
Please see [Content Density](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d935dbf196d34997bf1ac42ac3e81579.html)

Without the form factor CSS, the table Legacy Mode generates the +/- Images only.

As of version 1.40, this should no longer be required and +/- Icons should be replaced.